# Правильно ли я понимаю работу прототипов?

Tags: javascript, прототипное-наследование

Я уже который день пытаюсь с этим разобраться, поэтому не могли бы вы подсказать, правильно ли я уловил суть?

Когда мы создаём объект через функцию-конструктор, в самой функции, хотя мы его и не указывали, присутствует скрытое свойство prototype. В самом начале оно является простым объектом с сылкой на функцию-конструктор.

```js
function User(name, surname) {
  name = name,
  surname = surname
}

console.log(User.prototype);
```

Если мы хотим, чтобы новые экземпляры объекта унаследовали свойства из функции конструктора, у нас есть два варианта: мы можем добавить необходимые свойства прямиком в тело функции, либо в объект prototype. Но между этими двумя способами, конечно, есть различия.

Когда мы добавляем свойства прямиком в тело функции, они дублируются каждый раз при создании нового объекта.

Если же мы добавляем свойства в объект F.prototype, то оно создаётся один раз и находится только в этом объекте. Однако новый экземпляр объекта будет иметь доступ ко всем его ключам, но не к самому F.prototype.

```js
function User(name, surname) {
  this.name = name,
  this.surname = surname
}

User.prototype.sayHello = function () {
  return `Всем привет! Я функция, и я живу в объекте User.prototype`;
}

let user1 = new User('Vasya', 'Big');

console.log(user1) 
//не совсем понятно, почему здесь в консоли function показывается 
//внутри user1, в браузерной консоли он так не отображается
//должно быть User { name: 'Vasya', surname: 'Big' }

console.log(user1.sayHello()); // всё работает
```

И ещё один момент. Только вчера до меня дошло, что каждый раз, когда мы создаём какой-либо объект, даже используя литеральную нотацию, мы всё равно используем функцию-конструктор (Object).

```js
/*
function Object(value1, value2) {
  this.prop1 = value1,
  this.prop2 = value2
}

let anyObject = new Object(value1, value2);
*/

let anyObject = {
  prop1: value1,
  prop2: value2
}
```

Раньше я думал, что Object - это корневой объект, но на самом деле это функция-конструктор, у которого также есть свойство "prototype". И именно от объекта Object.prototype наследуются все встроенные методы новых объектов.

```js
console.log(typeof Object);                // function
console.log(typeof Object.prototype);      // object
 
Object.prototype.someString = 'какое-нибудь свойство';

let obj = {
  name: 'Vasya',
  surname: 'Big'
}

console.log(obj.someString); //какое-нибудь свойство
```

Если я где-то ошибаюсь или Вам есть, что дополнить — буду очень рад прочитать Ваши ответы.

Comment: В вашем вопросе не обнаружено вопроса :) `Object.property` - наверное, `Object.prototype`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko спасибо, уже исправил. Сколько бы материалов я не посмотрел, для меня всё это было не очевидно. Возможно, в них просто не делался на этом акцент, или же я просто долго соображаю, поэтому мне важно узнать, правильно ли это всё, или нет.

Comment: Все правильно, но не понятен ваш комментарий *//не совсем понятно, почему здесь в консоли function показывается 
//внутри user1, в браузерной консоли он так не отображается
//должно быть User { name: 'Vasya', surname: 'Big' }*

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko меня просто сбил с толку вывод в консоль на этом сайте, когда нажимаешь "Выполнить код". Почему-то тут в консоли показывается, что внутри user1 помимо свойств "name" и "surname" находится ещё и функция "sayHello".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Однако новый экземпляр объекта будет иметь доступ ко всем его ключам, но не к самому F.prototype

Не-а, доступ к прототипу тоже есть:

```js
function Test() {}

let obj = new Test();

console.log( Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === Test.prototype ); // true;
console.log( obj.__proto__ === Test.prototype ); // true;


console.log( obj.hasOwnProperty("__proto__") ); // false ?!
console.log( Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty("__proto__") ); // true!
```

`getPrototypeOf()` поддерживается от IE9 и выше.

`__proto__` — сильно устаревший способ доступа к prototype функции-конструктора. В консоли браузера оно отображается прямо в объекте, но его там нет, свойство-геттер наследуется от Object.prototype.

Comment: `__proto__` - это не способ, это и есть `getter` из `Object.prototype`. То, что хром, при отображении в консоли так же называет внутреннее поле - это уже заморочки хрома и они в принципе никак не связаны